# Как скрыть окно консольного приложения, чтобы оно при этом продолжало работать в фоне?

Tags: c#, dllimport, .net-4.8

```
namespace Producer
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll)")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        private static IPEndPoint consumerEndPoint;
        private static UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var consumerIp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerIp");
            var consumerPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerPort");
            consumerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(consumerIp), int.Parse(consumerPort));
            FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
            videoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame;
            videoSource.Start();
            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
        }

        private static void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, 800, 600);
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
                {
                    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, consumerEndPoint);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
         
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы не используете консоль в коде, зачем вообще его показывать тогда? Поменяйте в билде тип проекта  с Console Application на что нибудь более подходящее вам.

Comment: https://vk.com/video-142292681_456239431 я делал по этому видеоуроку. и на какой тип вы посоветуете поменять?

Comment: В настройках сборки стоит консольное, поменяйте на оконное. И вообще слелайте winforms со значком в системном лотке. Тогда можно будет управлять им при необходимости. Winforms Notification Icon.

Comment: Экономьте память, уберите `var bytes = ms.ToArray();` и напишите так `udpClient.Send(ms.GetBuffer(), ms.Position, consumerEndPoint);`. И еще `using var bmp = ...`, ненужный битмап диспозить надо.

Comment: Зачем кстати вы в битмап копируете, можно же сразу `eventArgs.Frame.Save(...)`